# EWS: Trying to find unique folder id

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exchangewebservices

I have tried to code a solution to finding unique folderids for Outlook, using the EWS API. For some reason the code isn't working, and I cannot quite figure out where the problem is. I don't have experience with the EWS API.

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
public class Class1
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {



        // Set server binding

        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
        service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        // Set Credentials
        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("xxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxx");
        service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        // Set the URL 
        service.AutodiscoverUrl("xxxxx");

        // Set View

        FolderView view = new FolderView(100);
        view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
        view.PropertySet.Add(FolderSchema.DisplayName);
        view.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;
        FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Root, view);

        // Find specific folder

        foreach (Folder f in findFolderResults)
        {

            // Show FolderId of the folder "test"
            if (f.DisplayName == "Test")
                Console.WriteLine(f.Id);
        }

    }
}
```

}

It says not handled exception, autodsicover blocked a potentially insecure redirection(..)

Answer (score 0):

When the error is raised, it mentions that you need to use a callback to allow redirects. Something along the lines

```
service.AutodiscoverUrl("xxxxx", ValidateRedirectionUrlCallback);
...
private static bool ValidateRedirectionUrlCallback(string url)
{
    // Validate the URL and return true to allow the redirection or false to prevent it.
    return true; //allow redirections
}
```